# Angular HotTowel ActivateController Promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using Angular HotTowel as a boiler plate for my application, but I am having trouble understanding the 'activateController' method, specifically, the way the `promises` are handled.

In HotTowel, all views are wrapped by the `shell` controller. My `shell` controller is:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

var controllerId = 'shell';
angular.module('app').controller(controllerId,
    ['$rootScope', 'common', 'config', 'myService', shell]);

function shell($rootScope, common, config, myService) {
    /*jshint validthis: true */
    var vm = this;
    var logSuccess = common.logger.getLogFn(controllerId, 'success');
    var events = config.events;
    vm.busyMessage = 'Please wait ...';
    vm.isBusy = true;
    vm.spinnerOptions = {
        radius: 40,
        lines: 7,
        length: 0,
        width: 30,
        speed: 1.7,
        corners: 1.0,
        trail: 100,
        color: '#BF2020'
    };

    activate();

    function activate() {
        var promises = [getScript()];
        logSuccess('Application Loaded!', null, true);
        $rootScope.title = 'Application ';
        common.activateController(promises, controllerId);
    }

    function getScript() {
        myService.getScript();
    }

    function toggleSpinner(on) { vm.isBusy = on; }

    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart',
        function (event, next, current) {
            $rootScope.title = next.title;
            toggleSpinner(true);
        }
    );

    $rootScope.$on(events.controllerActivateSuccess,
        function (data) { toggleSpinner(false); }
    );

    $rootScope.$on(events.spinnerToggle,
        function (data) { toggleSpinner(data.show); }
    );
}
})();
```

Focusing on the `getScript()` function in the promises, all it should do is call a service and return the script.

```
(function () {
'use strict';

var serviceId = 'myService';

angular.module('app').service(serviceId, ['common', myService]);

function myService(common) {
    var service = {
        getScript: getScript
    };

    return service;

    function getScript() {
        return $.getScript(myURL).then(function() {
            logSuccess("SUCCESSULLY LOADED");
        }, function () {
            logError("FAILED LOAD");
        });
    }
}
})();
```

I would expect this promise to be executed before the controllers of the inner-views load since the `activateController` method calls `$q.all()` on the promises.

```
function activateController(promises, controllerId) {
    return $q.all(promises).then(function (eventArgs) {
        var data = { controllerId: controllerId };
        $broadcast(commonConfig.config.controllerActivateSuccessEvent, data);
    });
}
```

However, I am noticing the exact opposite where the inner-view controllers are loaded, then the promise executes. Shouldn't the `shell` controller load, execute it's promises, then load any nested views and their promises?